Having trouble understanding a proof from Jech’s book
I’m trying to understand the proof of theorem 21.4 from Jech’s book (Silver’s forcing) but I haven’t been able to move from the first page. Is there any other book or paper that presents the same proof but maybe with a little more detail?
The theorem is:
“If there is a supercompact cardinal, $\kappa$, there is a generic extension in which $\kappa$ is measurable and $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$”

Post the theorem and proof in their entirety. Your question should be self contained.

@Malady that could potentially be a copyright violation.

@TheAlertGerbil I do not believe that is that case. I have never heard of a short passage from a book (especially a proof from a mathematical textbook) being removed on grounds of copyright infringement.

@Malady Unrealistic as this proof is like 5-10 pages long iirc. (But I agree they should be explicit about which theorem in a way that doesn’t rely on references.)

@spaceisdarkgreen I understand, I was not aware of that.

I agree. There are multiple things that can be referred to as Silver forcing. Which one is this?

I edited the question, sorry for that and thank you for your answers

@AsafKaragila  To me, "Silver forcing" means the one that adds a real; conditions are maps from a cofinite subset of $\omega$ to $2$. The forcing relevant to this question was called "reverse Easton forcing" in ancient times when I learned about it, but some people objected to that name, because it's Easton's forcing that "goes backward", adding subsets to larger cardinals "before" smaller ones, while the reverse version goes "forward".

In my previous comment, for "cofinite" read "coinfinite" and similarly correct any other stupidity.

@Andreas: Yes, that's what I figured. But just from a vague memory of Jech chapter 21 being possibly about large cardinals, I figured it might be something else. Looking at the edit, I was right.

I'm not sure if they will be more useful, but a couple other references would be Baumgartner's iterated forcing notes and James Cummings' handbook chapter on iterated forcing and elementary embeddings.

Thanks! I already looked at the Baumgartner one but not to the handbook
